# Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC Still Submit Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using ASP MVC 4 and I have both ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled appSettings turn on but when I submit a form with unobtrusive validation data attributes it get submitted even when it is invalid.
The validation message appear but the form still get submitted.

JavaScript is enabled in my browser off course.

Comment: Check if some scripts are missing.

Comment: without more info it is very hard helping you. check you don't have another javascript submit of the form, you don't have javascript library collisions or as @AdrianoSilva says you are not missing a script.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure, you have following libraries linked

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Check your configuration. These two should look as follows:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Don't forget to add:

```cs
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FieldToValidate)
```

Answer (score 5):

For MVC4 in your master page add below line

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

and make sure that in bundles.config below lines are present.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

once you have added jquery.unobtrusive  you will encounter below error.

the live() function is not available anymore in jquery 1.9, which has been deprecated.

```
TypeError: $(…).live is not a function
```

in order to resolve this you can manyally replace .live  with .On or just add beta release from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax -Pre
```